# AngularJS application to display 10 search results at a time

Tags: javascript, angular.js, pagination

I am working on an angular application. I have written a controller for a page which gets 10 objects from an api. On clicking the next button, it gets the next 10 objects and so on. I have also added a search box in the same controller which also gets 10 results of the searched term and on clicking the next button it gets the next 10 results.

HTML -

```
<!-- Show results -->
<div class="panel panel-default jobs" ng-repeat="job in jobs.jobsList">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center"><a href="{{job.career_url}}" target='_blank' class="hvr-sink"><h3 class="well">{{job.job_name}}</h3></a></div>
    <div class="panel-body text-center flexcontainer">
        <div>Company: {{job.company_name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Search buton and search box -->
<span class="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i></span><input ng-change="jobs.search()" ng-model="jobs.searchTerm" ng-keydown="jobs.deleteTerm($event)" type="text" id="search-box" style="width: 0px; visibility:hidden;"/>

<!-- Take to top of page button -->
<a href="#" id="back-to-top" title="Back to top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-2x"></i></a>

<!-- Get next ten results -->
<div ng-click="jobs.getNext()" class="nextButton">See More</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var toggleVar = true;
    $('.searchButton').on('click', function() {
        if(toggleVar) {
            $('.searchButton').animate({right: '210px'}, '1200');
            $('#search-box').css("visibility", "visible");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.searchButton').css("color", "#444444");
            }, 100);
            $('#search-box').animate({ width: 185 }, '1200').focus();
            toggleVar = false;
        }
        else {
            $('#search-box').animate({ width: 0 }, '1200');
            $('.searchButton').animate({right: '25px'}, '1200');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.searchButton').css("color", "#eeeeee");
            }, 200);
            toggleVar = true;
        }
    });

    $('#search-box').focusout(function() {
        if(!toggleVar) {
            $('#search-box').animate({ width: 0 }, '1200');
            $('.searchButton').animate({right: '25px'}, '1200');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.searchButton').css("color", "#eeeeee");
            }, 200);
            toggleVar = true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Controller -

```
angular.module('jobSeekerApp')
  .controller('JobsallCtrl', ['getAllJobs', 'searchJobs', function (jobsService, jobsSearchService) {
    var ctrl = this;
    var count;
    ctrl.pageNumber = 1; 
    ctrl.searchPageNumber = 1;
    ctrl.isSearching = false;
    ctrl.searchTerm = "";

    // Initial page load
    jobsService.getJobs(ctrl.pageNumber)
      .then(function(response) {
        ctrl.jobsList = response.data.results;
        count = response.data.count;
        checkCount();
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    // User clicks next button
    ctrl.getNext = function() {
      // If search is not being used
      if(ctrl.searchTerm === "" && ctrl.isSearching === false) {
        ctrl.pageNumber = ctrl.pageNumber + 1;
        jobsService.getJobs(ctrl.pageNumber)
          .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.jobsList = ctrl.jobsList.concat(response.data.results);
            checkCount(); 
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      // If search is being used
      else {
        ctrl.searchPageNumber = ctrl.searchPageNumber + 1;
        jobsSearchService.searchJob(ctrl.searchPageNumber, ctrl.searchTerm)
          .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.jobsList = ctrl.jobsList.concat(response.data.results);
            checkCount();
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } 
    };

    // User backspaces to delete search term
    ctrl.deleteTerm = function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        ctrl.searchTermLen = ctrl.searchTermLen - 1;
      }
      // If search box is empty
      if(ctrl.searchTermLen === 0) {
        ctrl.isSearching = false;
      }
    };

    // User clicks search button
    ctrl.search = function() {
      ctrl.searchTermLen = ctrl.searchTerm.length;
      // If search box is empty, show normal results
      if(ctrl.searchTerm === "" && ctrl.isSearching === false) {
        ctrl.pageNumber = 1;
        jobsService.getJobs(ctrl.pageNumber)
          .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.jobsList = response.data.results;
            count = response.data.count;
            checkCount();
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      // If search box is not empty, search the input
      else {
        ctrl.isSearching = true;
        ctrl.searchPageNumber = 1;
        jobsSearchService.searchJob(ctrl.searchPageNumber, ctrl.searchTerm)
          .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.jobsList = response.data.results;
            count = response.data.count;
            checkCount();
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    };

    // Function to hide and show next button
    function checkCount() {
      console.log(count);
      if(count < 10) {
        $(".nextButton").hide();
      }
      else {
        $(".nextButton").show();
      }
      count = count - 10;
    }
  }]);
```

I have added separate services for normal results and search results. 
Since the search box hides when out of focus and angular starts getting normal results after instead of search results, I added `isSearching` variable so it knows when the user is searching and when not.

Now, the application is working fine. But I feel there is a lot of repetition in the code and overall the quality is not good. I dont have much experience with JavaScript or Angular, so could anyone help with how i can improve the code. I think I could also use custom directives, but I am not sure where and for what functionality.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting swearing in your `console.log`. Try and clean up your code of obscenities before showing it to other people at least; it doesn't reflect well on you otherwise.

Comment: Some Improvements: **1.** In `checkCount()` use `$(".nextButton").toggle(count < 10);` **2.** Use Number as second param i.e. duration to `animate()`. Currently, strings are used `'1200'`. **3.** Instead of changing `color` by using `css()`, create a CSS class and toggle it using `toggleClass()`. Same for `visibility`. **4.** `toggleVar` is _global_. Avoid creating globals, wrap the code in IIFE. **5.** Try to minimize the use of jQuery, use Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the services work, I would, if possible, try to unify
getAllJobs and searchJobs to a single service JobService and use this
unified service.

Move ctrl.jobsList inside JobService, there is not particular reason why
this *has* to be handled by the controller. Instead, you could just do a
one to one ctrl.jobsList = JobService.jobsList in your controller. You will have to handle
your concats in the service as well.

Move checkCount function to html using ng-show:

```
<div ng-click="jobs.getNext()" class="nextButton" ng-show="checkCount()">See More</div>
```

This will give you more opportunities to clean up your controller a little bit, maybe something like this:

```
angular.module('jobSeekerApp')
.controller('JobsallCtrl', ['JobService', function (JobService) {

    var ctrl = this;
    var count;

    ctrl.jobsList = JobService.jobsList;
    count = JobService.count;

    ctrl.pageNumber = 1;
    ctrl.searchPageNumber = 1;
    ctrl.isSearching = false;
    ctrl.searchTerm = "";

    JobService.getJobs(ctrl.pageNumber);

    ctrl.getNext = function() {

        if(isSearch) {
            ctrl.searchPageNumber = ctrl.searchPageNumber + 1;
            JobService.searchJob(ctrl.searchPageNumber, ctrl.searchTerm);
            return;
        }

        ctrl.pageNumber = ctrl.pageNumber + 1;
        JobService.getJobs(ctrl.pageNumber);

    };

    ctrl.search = function() {
        ctrl.searchTermLen = ctrl.searchTerm.length;

        if(isSearch) {
            ctrl.isSearching = true;
            ctrl.searchPageNumber = 1;
            JobService.searchJob(ctrl.searchPageNumber, ctrl.searchTerm);
            return;
        }

        ctrl.pageNumber = 1;
        JobService.getJobs(ctrl.pageNumber);
    };

    ctrl.deleteTerm = function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            ctrl.searchTermLen = ctrl.searchTermLen - 1;
        }

        ctrl.isSearching = ctrl.searchTermLen !== 0;
    };

    ctrl.checkCount = function() {
        var result = count >= 10;
        count = count - 10;
        return result;
    };

    function isSearch() {
        return !(ctrl.searchTerm === "" && ctrl.isSearching === false);
    }

}]);
```

**HEADS UP!** This is just example code, untested.